# Rails - Building Conditional Statement

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to build my conditions like so:

```
conditions = {}
conditions[:doors] = 4
conditions[:type] = "sedan"

Cars.find(:all, :conditions=>conditions)
```

How would I add to my conditions for 'LIKE' conditions:

```
conditions[:color] NOT LIKE '%black%'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have Rails 3+ consider using the new AREL syntax for some of your query building:

```
records = Car.where(:doors => 4, :type => "sedan")
records = records.where("color NOT LIKE ?", "%black%")
```

But if you are still using Rails 2.3 then the syntax looks like:

```
clauses = ["doors = ?", "type = ?"]
conditions = [4, 'sedan']

if some_reason
  clauses << "color NOT LIKE ?"
  conditions << "%robert%"
end



Cars.find(:all, :conditions => [clauses.join(" AND" ), *conditions])
```

Definitely more annoying than than the AREL syntax.

A side-benefit of this syntax is that when ActiveRecord replaces the `?` it will sanitize the inputs for SQL injection.